# Is it possible to fix this race condition with my backbone app?

Tags: backbone.js, race-condition

I'm running into a possible race condition with Backbone.

When a user clicks the links on the left, back and forth, I get nested views eventually.

This usually happens when one click is still loading the view.

http://screencast.com/t/oLsZQga1

Is there something simple I can do to fix this? I've tried using _.debounce(), which works great locally, but once I put it into the test environment with real data, I begin to get nested views again.

**EDIT: Some code would probably help ;).**

This is the view for the two links on the left:

```
events: 
  "click" : "close"

initialize: =>
  super
  @close = _.debounce @_close, 1500, true

_close: (e) =>
  e.preventDefault() if e
  e.stopPropagation() if e
  id = @model.get('_id') || @model.get('id')
  @publishEvent "!router:route", "fan/#{id}"
```

This is the view for the results on the right:

```
attach: ->
  super
  $(".fanViewButton").parents("li:first").addClass("active")
  @initSubViews()
  @updateFanHistory()

initSubViews: ->
  @subview("memberDataView", new GeneralInfo({container:'div.left .row-fluid', model:@model}))
  @subview("fanHand", new FanHand({container: @$el.find('.fanHandContainer'), model: @model}))
  @subview("gatherInfo", new GatherInfo({container: @$el.find('.gatherInfoContainer'), model: @model}))
  @subview("fanScores", new FanScores({container:@$el.find('.center .row-fluid'), model : @model}))
  @setHeight()
```

If you need more stuff, just let me know as I'm really new to Backbone.

Thanks, everyone :).

Comment: Can you share your code logic?

Comment: Of course, sorry about that :).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your just not removing the subviews. If on the close function you make sure to remove anything inside of the container for the subview it should clear the DOM for you. Something like: `$('.subviewContainer').remove()`